# Can i use or in .replace function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a temperature converter. It convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa. The code I wrote is:

```
user_input = input("Insert the temperature you would like to convert: ")
user_num = user_input.replace('F' or 'C', '')
user_temp = float(user_num)


if ('F' in user_input or 'f' in user_input):
  print(((user_temp - 32) * 5/9), 'C') # conversion from F to C

elif ('C' in user_input or 'c' in user_input): 
  print(((user_temp * 9/5) + 32), 'F') # conversion fron C to F

else: 
  print("Try again.")
```

I can convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, but can't do the opposite.
When I try to convert c to f i get
   `user_temp = float(user_num) ValueError: could not convert string to float: '36C'`

Also, I want to make the code so it replaces either 'F' or 'f' and 'C' or 'c'.

What I can fix in order to make this work?

Comment: Do you have any error raised?

Comment: `'F' or 'C'` does not do what you think it does. It always chooses `'F'`, as `or` selects the the first that is true. Since string literals are always true, it'll return `'F'`.

Comment: sry forgot to edit the error. edited now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'F' or 'C'` just evaluates to `'F'`. I don’t think this is what you want. You can either replace twice:

```py
user_num = user_input.replace('F', '').replace('C', '')
```

or use a RegEx:

```py
import re

user_num = re.sub('F|C', '', user_input)
```

I think your later `'f'` and `'c'` should probably be capitalised.

Comment: It's a nice idea to use regex, +1. I would suggest to put 'F|C|f|c' as first argument anyway.

Comment: Thank you!
I'll look into regex more.
I just started learning python so I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_num = user_input.replace('F' or 'C', '')
```

Look at the line above: it will only search for `'F'` since the `or` logic operator doesn't work the way you expected.

This will work instead:

```
for i in ['F', 'C']:
    user_num = user_input.replace(i, '')
```

or also a double `.replace` call:

```
user_num = user_input.replace('F', '').replace('C', '')
```

---

Oterwise you could consider a `regex` solution, as @LeopardShark suggested, that needs a module and is a less-beginner solution.

Comment: `if i in user_input:` is unnecessary as `.replace` will not do anything if it's not in the string.

Comment: Ok, nice to know, I thought there should have been an exception raised.

Comment: Oh right, but now you won't break, and the variable will be overridden. My bad